# What is limit to physical number of raster TIFFS that can be placed in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, geotiff-tiff, limitations

Can anyone please let me know if there is a limit to the physical number of raster TIFFS that can be placed in QGIS?

I am trying to bring in a large number of StreetView tiffs from the Ordnance Survey OpenData suite, but have reached a point where I get an error message.

I have imported 1,998 tiles without any problems. When I import the next single file, it doesn't geo-reference correctly. Then the next one brings up the following error message:

"/OS_OpenData/StreetView/no/no05nw.tif is not a supported raster data source"

I am running QGIS 2.12 Lyon on Mac OS X El Capitan (10.10.5). The GDAL version is 1.11.3-1. This also happened on the previous QGIS version (Pisa), so I upgraded today to see if that fixed it.

Comment: Does it always fall over on the same TIFF?

Comment: Check the maximum number of open files:  "launchctl limit maxfiles"

Answer (score 1):

There is a limit to the number of files that may be opened by a single process on OSX, and it can be quite low.  I had a problem working with a time series of tiles and had to increase my limits.

Try this on the command line so see some of the process limits:

```
ulimit -a
ulimit -Ha
launchctl limit maxfiles
```

If these limits are close to 2000, that could be your problem and it could be resolved through something like https://superuser.com/questions/433746/is-there-a-fix-for-the-too-many-open-files-in-system-error-on-os-x-10-7-1  or http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/tuning/open-files-limit/#Mac-OS-X

My current results for these are:

```
499 [drf@v21837 ~]$ ulimit -a 
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 65536
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 2048
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
500 [drf@v21837 ~]$ ulimit -Ha
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 65536
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 65532
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 2048
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
501 [drf@v21837 ~]$ launchctl limit maxfiles
    maxfiles    65536          65536          
502 [drf@v21837 ~]$
```

Note that the maxfiles == 65335

My machine's currently a Mac OSX 10.10.5 and I have a /Library/LaunchDaemons/limit.maxfiles.plist per the http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/tuning/open-files-limit/#Mac-OS-X link like this:

```
512 [drf@v21837 ~]$ sed 's/^/    /' /Library/LaunchDaemons/limit.maxfiles.plist  
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
  <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
      <key>Label</key>
        <string>limit.maxfiles</string>
      <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
          <string>launchctl</string>
          <string>limit</string>
          <string>maxfiles</string>
          <string>65536</string>
          <string>65536</string>
        </array>
      <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
      <key>ServiceIPC</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
  </plist>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have had a go at the two options on these websites, but I am not a big Terminal user and I think I am not doing something right, as neither seem to work. I really need an idiots guide to get these working!

Comment: Let me look at it more to see if I can figure out exactly what I did.

Comment: To set the limits at the system level, you have to reboot.  I seem to remember that if you set them too high, they revert to defaults and ignore the settings.  Are your max files limits as seen within a Terminal close to the 2000 files where you are experiencing a problem?

Comment: I wonder if there's any mileage in the idea of 'combining' the files into a virtual raster file, a VRT (*.vrt)? Raster -> Miscellaneous -> Build Virtual Raster. You'd have to set some sensible extents before loading the file into QGIS, or QGIS would try to load the lot.